# Question on debugging a Silverlight app in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight

Im trying to debug my first Silverligt 3 app.  I have it linked to a web project.  The problem is that if an exception occurs, I get a popup that tells me to choose a debugger, and after doing so says something like "There is already a debugger attached".  Im used to WinForms where, if an exception is thrown VS breaks at that point and shows me where it is thrown.  Is this type of behavior possible with Silverlight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to debug your silverlight apps in exactly the same fashion as with winforms. Are your debugging settings correct? You should have your web application set as the startup project and make sure that silverlight debugging is enabled for the silverlight project, and asp.net debugging is enabled for the web app. Also make sure you are not building in release mode.